# BeautifulSoup find_all give me the value of the last element only

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hello hope you're all doing well I wrote the following program to extract the data from it's source but it gives me the last value and I don't know why

```
users_list = soup.find_all("li", class_= "ContentGrid-gridItem-2Ad e2e-ContentGriditem")
for user in users_list:

name = user.find("span", class_ = "e2e-UserSummary-displayName")
profile_link = user.find('a', class_='UserSummary-ownerLink-1cJ')
```

the variable profile_link gives me this output

```
<a class="UserSummary-ownerLink-1cJ" 
href="https://www.behance.net/baianat?tracking_source=search_users" 
target="_blank"></a>
```

i want to make it return only the link

another thing also I built other variables to return values but it keep returning the same values because it's having the same class and they all in h4 here's the code and it's returning the value of the first object which is appreciations 189.9k

```
appreciations = users.find("h4", class_= "UserSummaryStats-statAmount-13R").text
followers = users.find("h4", class_= "UserSummaryStats-statAmount-13R").text
project_views = users.find("h4", class_= "UserSummaryStats-statAmount-13R").text
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract only href attribute of the tag you can use **[`tag['<attr>']`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes)**. For example:

```
profile_link = user.find('a', class_='UserSummary-ownerLink-1cJ')['href']
```

For the second case, just use **[`.find_all(<tag_name>, <params>)`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all)** method which returns all the tags with defined parameters as a list:

```
user_data = users.find_all("h4", class_= "UserSummaryStats-statAmount-13R")
for entry in user_data:
    # do something with each entry
```